# How to close dropdown menu when clicking somewhere else and also changing OnClick style on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, onclick

I just finished creating two buttons with an `onclick` event,

You can view the demo of the buttons [here.](http://codepen.io/Conscious/pen/npgtA/)

However, I need help with two issues which I'm not sure how I can solve.

**Issue 1**

As you can see in the demo, if you first click a button, a dropdown menu appears, but if you click on the second button while the first dropdown menu is visible, the second dropdown overlaps the first dropdown menu.

How can I close the dropdown when you click somewhere else on the page or on another button using javascript?

**Issue 2**

I want the button to look like this even if you hover over the button

[image: button-before-click]

And this is how it's going to look when you click the button and when the dropdown menu becomes visible. It should stay like this even if you don't have your mouse on the button or the dropdown menu.

[image: button-after-click]

How can I accomplish this with JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep an array of your elements, when you set one to display, set the others not to.

```
var dropdowns = ['language', 'delivery-country'];
var elements = [];

var hideElements = function (dropdown) {
  for (var i = 0, l = dropdowns.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (dropdown !== dropdowns[i]) {
        var div = document.getElementById(dropdowns[i] + '-dropdown');
          div.style.display = '';      
        elements[i].className = 'inactive';
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0, l = dropdowns.length; i < l; i++) {
  elements[i] = document.getElementById(dropdowns[i] + '-icon');

  (function (index) {
    elements[index].onclick = function() {
      var div = document.getElementById(dropdowns[index] + '-dropdown');

        if (div.style.display !== '') {
            div.style.display = '';
          elements[index].className = 'inactive';
        } else {
            div.style.display = 'block';
          elements[index].className = 'active';
      }
      hideElements(dropdowns[index]);
    };
  })(i);
}
```

For the second part of your question, add the respective classes in your html (inactive).  The code above will toggle the classes, you just need to figure out the CSS.  Start by removing the hover classes on the icons, and also use classes for the icons rather than ids which you need to specify for every element.